# How to create and maintain a multi-language project?

Tags: c#, desktop-application, multilingual, containers

I am planning to make a multi-language application in C# and was wondering what is the best way to handle the follow:

- The container for the languages;
- Best approaches to read/change once
  initiated/requested;
- As the program grows so does the the
  text for each language what do you
  usually do and recommend as best
  practice;
- What sort of problems have you
  encountered while doing such type of
  applications;

Thanks for any advice, replies, etc.

I would really appreciate links and sample code if it's not too much trouble (not required, only if you have the time and can).

Comment: a downvote without a comment is just like a person that votes without meaning. Come forth and tell me your reason at least.

Comment: Wasn't me, but I think the question is too generic. Maybe split into: how to create a multi-language project? How to store data (giving more details about the domain), how to handle i18n? etc.

Comment: Thanks for the input Mau i will rework it now... i am very unsure on how to re-write it tought

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that the standard way to localize a C# app is using resources and satellite assemblies. Here are some articles about this:

[Creating and Implementing Satellite Assemblies](http://sharpertutorials.com/creating-and-implementing-satellite-assemblies/)
[Localization Like the Pros](http://en.csharp-online.net/Localization_Like_the_Pros)
MSDN: [Localizing Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z68135h5.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer ho1 i will take a look at it, hope the question looks better now.

Answer (score 1):

To handle languages the best way is to store strings in a resource file. You can release additional languages with satellite assemblies. You will find a lot of information about globalization and localization with C#: for example in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1021kkz0(v=VS.71).aspx)

If you are planning to store much data, i would suggest SQL Compact + NHibernate. XML is very slow especially with C#.

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure if it will be that much data at the start but i am sure it will grow over time with new features...

Answer (score 1):

Like everyone said, using a resource file is good way to store the localization data. Starting from that point you can find some approaches, the most common approaches could be using satellite assembly or using a file based resource manager.

On my personal opinion, I think satellite assembly helps your project to be more flexible and obviously helps with extensibility (I think many comercial software uses this approach).

On the next link you can find information about the two approaches.

[.NET - Localization using Resource file](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Localization.aspx)

The next link is a really good article aboud localization and base concepts.

[Internationalization & Localization](http://www.suodenjoki.dk/us/productions/articles/localization.htm)

Hope it helps.